# What is the definition of surjective morphism of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, when talking about the surjectivity of $f$, there are at least several possibilities.

(1) $f$ is surjective at the level of sets, that is $\forall \  y \in Y$, there exist $x \in X$, such that $f(x)=y$.

(2) $f$ is surjective in the sense of category morphisms. This means for any scheme $Z$, and morphisms $g_1, g_2 : Y \to Z$ such that $g_1 \circ f=g_2 \circ f$ implies $g_1 =g_2$.

(3)$f$ is surjective at the level of schemes, i.e. $\overline{f(X)} = Y$. This seems unlikely to be correct definition of surjectivity, and I do not know how to make sense of the scheme structure of the closure of $f(X)$ (that is $\overline{f(X)}$). But if $Y$ is reduced, then there is no ambiguity.

My question is two folds:
(1) Which is "correct" definition of surjective morphism between schemes. (2) Since both definition 1 and 2 seems reasonable in some sense, are they equivalent? If $Y$ is reduced scheme, are three definitions equivalent?

Comment: Just use whatever concept is appropriate for whatever problem you need to address.

Comment: The third one is the definition of $f$ being _dominant_.  The second is usually called being an epimorphism (in the category of schemes).  The first is what people usually mean when they say surjective, see e.g. the Stacks project.

Comment: @Adeel Great! This justify my guess from reading the literature. But is there any possibility that the first and the second definition are the same?

Comment: @Li Yutong: certainly not!

Comment: You may be interested in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56564/what-are-the-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-schemes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1) The correct definition of "surjective" for a morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y $ is that the underlying map of sets $|f|:|X|\to |Y|$ be surjective.
"Correct" means "as decreed by  Grothendieck" : Cf. EGAI, Chap. I, Prop 3.5.2 .

2) The  categorical  notion mentioned in your point (2) is called *epimorphism*.

3) If $\overline{f(X)} = Y$, we say that $f$ is dominant.
This is much weaker than surjectivity (even for reduced schemes), as witnessed by the inclusion of any  dense open strict subset  of a scheme, say $\mathbb A^1\setminus \{0\}\hookrightarrow \mathbb A^1$.

4) Surjective morphisms needn't be epimorphisms:

Let $k$ be a field and let $X=Spec(k)$, $Y=Spec(k[T]/(T^2))=k[\epsilon]$ be  respectively the simple point and the double point over $k$.
Let     $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ be the closed immersion of the simple point into the double point corresponding to the $k$-algebra morphism $k[\epsilon]\to k$ sending $\epsilon$ to $0$.
The two $k$-algebra morphisms $k[\epsilon]\to k[\epsilon]$ sending $\epsilon$ to respectively $0$ and $\epsilon $ give rise to two morphisms $g_1, g_2:Y\to Y$ satisfying $g_1 \circ f=g_2 \circ f$ but  $g_1 \neq g_2$.
Hence the scheme morphism  $f:X\to Y$ is not an epimorphism although it is surjective,  as are all maps between  singleton sets.

5) Epimorphisms needn't be surjective (?):

Let $Y=\mathbb A^1_k$ (with $k$ an algebraically closed field) and $X$ be the discrete scheme obtained from the disjoint union (=coproduct) of all the closed points of $Y$.
The natural morphism $f:X\to Y$ has image $Y$ minus the generic point of $\mathbb A^1_k$ and is thus not surjective.
However it should be an epimorphism, but I haven't written out a proof of that.

Comment: @Martin: why not?

Comment: @Martin: I'm baffled by your comment. Not only do you not give any proof nor explanation nor hint for your statement, but in a comment to the OP you refer to a question of yours on MathOverflow where you quote  an [exercise sheet](http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math256/problems-9.pdf) whose exercise 8 **confirms** that my example in 5) **is** an epimorphism!

Comment: @Martin: Dear Martin, Just thinking it through, it seems that (5) is epi.  What am I missing?  Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your confirmation, dear @Matt.

Comment: Dear Georges, You're welcome!  Here was my reasoning (probably the same as yours): Given maps $f, g: X = \mathbb A^1_k \to S$, choose any open affine Spec $A$ of $S$, and pull-back to $X$.  Since the pull-backs to $Y$ coincides, these pull-backs contain the same closed points, and so are the same, say equal to Spec $k[x, p(x)^{-1}].$  Thus we are reduced to the considering the situation of $$A \to k[x,p(x)^{-1}] \to \prod_{a \in k, p(a) \neq 0} k,$$ and we use that the second map is an injection.  Best wishes,

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: Does the counterexample (4) depend on $Y$ being non-reduced? I.e. is there a surjective morphism to a reduced scheme that is not an epimorphism in the category of schemes?